# JQuery Waypoint Scroll Stop at Footer

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-waypoints

I am using JQuery Waypoint to scroll the left side navigation.  How can I stop the scroll before the footer?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var $jq = jQuery.noConflict();

$jq(document).ready(function() {

$jq('.top').addClass('hidden');
 $jq.waypoints.settings.scrollThrottle = 30;


$jq("#toc").waypoint(function(event, direction) {
    $jq('.top').toggleClass('hidden', direction === "up");

    if (direction === 'down') {
        var cssObj = {'position' : 'fixed', 'top' : '3px', 'left' : '100px'}
    }
    else {
        var cssObj = {'position' : 'absolute', 'top' : '3px', 'left' : '100px'}
    }
    $jq('#toc').css(cssObj);
},{
    offset: '3'
});



 });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set another waypoint for the footer whose offset is equal to the height of the `#toc` element **plus** any padding, borders, and positioning additions.

So maybe something like:

```
var toc = $("#toc");
$("footer").waypoint(function(event,direction){
    toc.css({
        position: "absolute",
        bottom: "403px"
    });
},{
    offset: toc.height() + 6
});
```

This way, once it detects that the amount of room between the top of the footer and the top of the page is equal to the total height of the `#toc` element, it'll go back to `position:absolute` and a `bottom` value of `403px`. Adjust this to match the height of the footer and accommodate for the spacing you desire between the footer and the `#toc` element.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/wrwkp/)'s an example.

Comment: @aje: Working on it now--gimme a moment.

Comment: Found the solution though: applying the logic from the question - on scroll down, apply styles, on scroll up, remove them!  I put that inside the second waypoint and found success.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I implemented it using the newest version of Waypoint, including unsticking the element when you scroll back up.

```
$('footer').waypoint({
    handler: function(direction) {
        if (direction == 'down') {
            $moduleTop.css({
                position: "absolute",
                top: $nextModule.offset().top - $moduleTop.outerHeight()
            });
        }
        else if (direction == 'up') {
            $moduleTop.css({
                position: '',
                top: ''
            });
        }
    },
    offset: $moduleTop.height()
});
```